# Swagger 3.0 reDoc Discriminator JSON

Tags: swagger, documentation, swagger-3.0

I'm currently writing swagger 3.0 documentation and using reDoc to render as nice UI for it. I have a few scenarios in my documentation where based on a previous properties enum I would want to display different schema object properties. Sadly I cant seam to figure out how to wire this together properly in my documentation. So far I have the following test endpoint:

```
{
  "post": {
    "operationId" : "test",
    "summary": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "tags": [ "test" ],
    "consumes": "application/json",
    "requestBody": {
      "required": true,
      "content": {
        "application/json": {
          "schema": {
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "$ref": "./schemas/test1.json"
              },
              {
                "$ref": "./schemas/test2.json"
              }
            ],
            "discriminator": {
              "propertyName": "pet_type",
              "mapping": {
                "click": "./schemas/test1.json",
                "open": "./schemas/test2.json"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Success"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The test1.json looks like this:

```
{
  "Cat": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "pet_type": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "hunts": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "age": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    },
    "discriminator": {
      "propertyName": "pet_type"
    }
  }
}
```

And the test2.json like this:

```
{
  "Dog": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "pet_type": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "bark": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "breed": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "Dingo",
          "Husky",
          "Retriever",
          "Shepherd"
        ]
      }
    },
    "discriminator": {
      "propertyName": "pet_type"
    }
  }
}
```

The desired out come would be to toggle between the two "test" jsons based on an enum (the drop down seen in the reDoc sample). What am I missing to get this result?
You can see an example of the discriminator result [here](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc) under the feature section (the first gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more digging I was able to figure out the issue... my structure for the most part.
On my index.json file I updated my components section to point at my components folder containing the schema as such:

```
"components": {
   "$ref": "./components/test.json"
},
```

The test.json looks like the following:

```
{
  "schemas": {
    "Refinance": {
      "description": "A representation of a cat",
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/schemas/Pet"
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "huntingSkill": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "The measured skill for hunting",
              "default": "lazy",
              "enum": [
                "clueless",
                "lazy",
                "adventurous",
                "aggressive"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "huntingSkill"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Purchase": {
      "description": "A representation of a dog",
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/schemas/Pet"
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "packSize": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int32",
              "description": "The size of the pack the dog is from",
              "default": 1,
              "minimum": 1
            },
            "foobar": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "some ol bullshit"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "packSize"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Pet": {
      "type": "object",
      "discriminator": {
        "propertyName": "petType"
      },
      "properties": {
        "petType": {
          "description": "Type of a pet",
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "xml": {
        "name": "Pet"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And finally the schema for the endpoint gets referenced as follows:

```
"requestBody": {
      "required": true,
      "content": {
        "application/json": {
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "../../index.json#/components/schemas/Pet"
          }
        }
      }
    },
```